# WPF Ribbon Button enable status doesn't sync with corresponding QAT button

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I define a Ribbon with a Ribbon Button.

```
<Ribbon x:Name="ribbonMenu" Background="White" Loaded="ribbonMenu_Loaded">
    <RibbonTab Header="{StaticResource File}">
        <RibbonGroup Header="{StaticResource File}">
            <c1:C1DockPanel>
                <RibbonButton Name="mMasterMaintaince" Label="{StaticResource mMasterMaintaince}" QuickAccessToolBarId="mWebpack"
                                      LargeImageSource="/WpfDemo;component/Resources/Images/icon.ico"
                                      SmallImageSource="/WpfDemo;component/Resources/Images/icon.ico"
                                      RibbonTwoLineText.HasTwoLines="True"
            </c1:C1DockPanel>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
<Button x:Name="enable" Content="Enable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Height="29" Click="button_Click"/>
```

Basically when user click enable button it will toggle the enable status of the mMasterMaintaince ribbon button (through IsEnable property of the ribbon button).

Everything works fine until I try to add the mMasterMaintaince to the Quick Access Toolbar.

When user press the enable button, only the mMasterMaintaince ribbon button's enable status is toggled, the corresponding Quick Access Toolbar button doesn't change the state.

I thought they are the same button.

I know that in the event handler of enable button I could loop through ribbonMenu.QuickAccessToolBar.Items to find the corresponding button and change its enable state but I wonder if there is more elegant way to do it.